# Best way for a beginner to become involved in cybersecurity?

Tags: linux, javascript, kali-linux, python, c

So I understand cyber security is a very broad topic but all sections I presume require some base skill.

I have a moderate understanding of Python and HTML but all are still very basic. For my Gold D of E (a qualification, as you will, organised by a UK-wide charity) I must spend 18 months developing a 'skill'. Because I have an interest in computers and would like to pursue a cyber-security career later in life, I have chosen cybersecurity as my skill.

Does anyone have any ideas where to start? I've currently set a timeline (in the 18 months) of learning C, then work around Linux/Bash, move onto learning JS, then networks, then finishing with learning the basic ins and outs of the Kali Linux package.

Does this seem achievable in 18 months?

Should I focus on getting a very high degree of knowledge on one language/skill or focus on a wider range of languages/skills at a lower degree of knowledge?

Is C and JS the way to go or should I advance in Python or learn something like C++ or Perl?

Cheers, Adam

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69358/discussion-on-question-by-adam-bromiley-best-way-for-a-beginner-to-become-involv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard answer is: it depends.  Cybersecurity is a HUGE domain with a lot of opportunity.

For instance, there are people who go threat hunting - they monitor network traffic and look for variance in there to understand what's out of the norm.  For those folks, an in-depth knowledge of networking is valuable.

Perimeter security is important.  That also involves a great level of knowledge of networking, packet inspection, and network monitoring tools.

Then there are people who are involved in application-level security.  Having skills in multiple programming languages would be valuable here.

There are people who specialize in hardening devices themselves and device security.  In that case, knowing Linux and Windows security at a deep level, along with a basic understanding of networking, is valuable.

There are people who do penetration testing.  For them, an in-depth knowledge of networking and electronics is valuable, as well as psychology (to hack the human factor).  Also deep familiarity with known vulnerabilities is important.

In some enterprises, administering the firewall falls under the Security Team.  There, a good knowledge of Network traffic, ports, and a basic knowledge of known good/bad hosts would be useful.  (That may be seen as an entry-level IT Security responsibility.)

In light of the above, there are multiple more possibilities that I haven't touched on.

If it were me, I'd suggest finding something to be excellent at.  Once you have deep knowledge, that may transfer over to other areas.  So if you are excellent at Python, the knowledge of how to do something programmatically would transfer over to C++ - you'd know what to do but would just need to figure out how to write the code.  Knowing what to do is the hard part; writing code to do it is easier.

If you want to work in a medical environment, knowledge of HIPAA (in the US) is valuable.  I assume that the UK has its own privacy laws, so knowing them for the medical environment would also have value if that's the route you want to go.  There an understanding of an electronic medical record as well as database security would be invaluable.

I've read that Perl is, although not dying, also not as popular as it used to be.  Given the choice, I'd think that staying with Python, which you understand a little of, would give you the quickest route toward understanding programming. The concepts are the same across platforms (the concepts behind if and loops don't change; only their operation and coding).

I'd welcome comments from some of the other folks here, but my first recommendation would be to find what you are really interested in and passionate about, and then study that.  Find something that you just can't put down and learn the heck out of that.  You'll be doing it 40+ hours per week and will always be learning more, so why not make a living at something you enjoy?

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. So I guess knowing a high-level language and a base in networking is a must, then you can branch off into different areas?

Comment: @AdamBromiley I'd say having a base in networking is a must.  After that, deciding where you want to focus would determine where to study next.  There's a certain mindset that is important - I'd suggest being thorough and curious are critical capabilities.  Finding something and saying, "hmmm.... what is this?" is important.  Also looking at configurations of the devices in question and knowing where to find best practices and resources is a must.  Being able to speak convincingly is also an important quality.  A good place to start would be to attend a local security conference.

Comment: Ah okay - cheers for the info. I'm looking at public lectures at Oxford University right now to do with cyber security actually :)